# Dual mode 802.11n PCI adapters

Tags: wireless-networking, pci, 802.11n

I have recently bought a DLink DIR-825 router. It is a dual mode (2.4GZ & 5GHZ) 802.11n wireless access point/router.

What is a good PCI adapter to pair with it? DLink appear to only make one dual mode adapter, which is the DWA-160 USB adapter. They don't seem to have a PCI adapter in their range, which seems very strange. Do any of the other network manufacturers make a good dual mode adapter?

Answer (score 1):

If you must go with a PCI solution, this should be what you are looking for:

[Wireless-N PCI Adapter with Dual-Band](http://www.linksysbycisco.com/US/en/products/WMP600N)
[$64.99 with Free Shipping on Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833124342&Tpk=WMP600N)

If you are willing to use a USB adapter, my friend has this one (and really likes it) and it has the additional benefit of being able to move it between machines easily:

[Wireless-N USB Network Adapter with Dual-Band](http://www.linksysbycisco.com/APAC/en/products/WUSB600N)
[$63.15 with Free Shipping on Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833124278&cm_re=WUSB600N-_-33-124-278-_-Product)

Apparently the pictures on Newegg are of Rev.1 of the USB adapter but they are shipping out Rev. 2, the one pictured on the Linksys site. I would verify this with Newegg before purchasing though.